# SAML error "SignatureStatus: NOT_PRESENT"

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

### UPDATE

I found that if I add a trusted cert to `SPOptions.ServiceCertificates` and set `SPOptions.AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SigningBehavior.IfIdpWantAuthnRequestsSigned;` and set `IdentityProvider.WantAuthnRequestsSigned = true`, the signature element is included.

---

## Original Question:

Having troubles connecting to an IDP with the following `AuthnRequest`:

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="idf299bf8aa08542d193e022cb047e5ecc" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2019-07-23T00:10:13Z" Destination="https://example-idp.com" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://example-sp.com/Acs">
<saml2:Issuer>https://example-sp.com</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

The IDP says: **"SignatureStatus: NOT_PRESENT"**. I'm guessing that means that the `authnrequest` should have a `<ds:Signature` section? If so, how do I configure `Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2` to include it?

The metadata xml I received from the idp contains a `<ds:Signature` section, but looking at the source code for `Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2`, it looks like that part of the metadata gets ignored when deserializing?

I'm not very familiar with the internals of SAML, so sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to generate a self-signed .pfx file that contains both your public cert and private key. We use azure key vault, but you could also use openssl. Lots of resources that explain how to generate one of those and load it into a c# `X509Certificate2` instance.

Once you have an instance of `X509Certificate2`, set `options.SPOptions.AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SigningBehavior.IfIdpWantAuthnRequestsSigned;`

And set `IdentityProvider.WantAuthnRequestsSigned = true`.

And then add the `X509Certificate2` instance like so: `options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(myX509Certificate2);`

Then run your app and start the SAML SSO process. You can use hookbin or the like to see what it sends in the `AuthnRequest` for `SAMLRequest`. You can extract the xml from that by url decoding it and then base64 decoding it like so in javascript, for instance to confirm signature xml is set and correct: `atob(decodeURIComponent(samlRequestValue))`